# Want to shorten links using bitly api with js

Tags: javascript, zapier

So, I am using Zapier.com for my High school project.
in which inside the zapier it has a Node js server which provides a async fucntion to runs some codes.
I want to shorten urls using javascript code in the code by zapier pathway so that any links provided will get shortened.
Inputs have no problem .
I get the links and can produce them in the output.
but when i use js with bitly api unable to get an output .
Errors encountered are : [object OBject]  OR undefined.

Comment: You need to give us the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello Mikey!**

`[object Object]` is the default value that you get when trying to stringify an object.
To debug this I recommend console logging the object, this will show you all the properties that it contains!

`undefined` means you are trying to access something that is not defined (hence the name),
To fix this, once again: try to log the entire object and then navigating yourself from there!

Hope this helped :)